# Animate width of SKSpriteNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

What options are there to animate the width of a SKSpriteNode? The goal is to implement a custom progress bar in a SKScene, but scaling the width is creating [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178554/swift-progress-bar-jumps-when-using-scaling-action). Is there another way to animate the width of a SKSpriteNode?